# How to pass a variable from blog.php through to intro_image

Tags: category-blog

I have

**blog.php**

**blog_item.php**

and then the layout 
**intro_image.php**

I wanted to count the number of blog posts, which is already being done in leading and intro articles in the blog.

But how can I pass that variable to either **blog_item.php** or to the layout **intro_image.php**.

I see that there is `$displayData` in the layout file, so perhaps I can pass the value to that object somehow so I can retrieve it?

I know I can `get` things how can I `set` things?

One of the reasons for wanting to know this is because in the `foreach` loop there is a `$counter++` and if I know what is the current number I can apply a bit of code to every 3rd item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are some different ways** to get the number of articles (I think that is what you mean under blog items), I'll just give you one example.

First, you have to access the article list model:

You can do that the usual way like (I have not checked this in Joomla 3.9):

```
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array( 'ignore_request' => true ));
```

Or you can do that with using newer classes like this (I use this in Joomla 3.9):

```
// on the top of your layout file:

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
use \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\BaseDatabaseModel;

BaseDatabaseModel::addIncludePath('components/com_content/models', 'ContentModel');

$model = BaseDatabaseModel::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
// var_dump($model); // just to check it
$numberOfItems = count($model->getItems());

echo "This is the total of items: " . $numberOfItems . "<br>";
```

When you have the list model then you just use the `getItems()` method of that and count the items.

And the reason I’m a bit avoiding your question about how to pass a variable among layouts and views is because those variables’ values are coming from the models too (created in the views), thus you can get and create them by accessing the models directly if you need them.

**UPDATE ON GETTING CONTENT PARAMS**

If you need for example the number of leading articles or the number of intro articles only, then since these are set in com_content parameters thus you can reach those values from anywhere in Joomla and get those data directly from the content params (registry object), using the component helper:

```
$content_params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');
// var_dump($content_params); // you can check all of the available params of com_content
$number_leading = $content_params->get('num_leading_articles');
$number_intro = $content_params->get('num_intro_articles');
echo "number of leading articles: " . $number_leading . "<br>";
echo "number of intro articles: " . $number_intro . "<br>";
```

The other part of your question on this like: what if there are not enough articles for intro then the number from the set parameters would be incorrect. I do not fully understand that part of your question. I do not see what exactly you want to accomplish to figure out a solution on that.

**UPDATE ON PASSING THE INTRO ITEMS AND LEAD ITEMS COUNTER VALUE OF ITEMS FROM *blog.php* to *blog_item.php***

As the particular variable needed was cleared more in the comments then the use of content params is still a viable option to pass the **foreach loop counter value** for each items from **blog.php** to **blog_item.php**.

in **blog.php** you call and define the content params (like I already did above):

```
$content_params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');
```

And within the **lead items' foreach loop** you set a variable (before the code line: `echo $this->loadTemplate('item');`)

```
$content_params->set('lead_count_number', $leadingcount + 1);
```

And within the **intro items' foreach loop** you set a variable (before the code line: `echo $this->loadTemplate('item');`)

```
$content_params->set('intro_count_number', $counter + 1);
```

This way you can call and check this param value item by item if needed in **blog_item.php**:

```
$content_params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');
$introCounterNumb = $content_params['intro_count_number'];
$leadCounterNumb = $content_params['lead_count_number'];
if (isset($introCounterNumb)){
    echo "this is the intro item's number: " . $introCounterNumb; // or do whatever
}
if (isset($leadCounterNumb)) {
    echo "this is the lead item's number: " . $leadCounterNumb;
}
```

**A SIMPLER SOLUTION**

you can avoid using content params if you just simply define a variable in **blog.php** inside both foreach loops like:

```
$this->lead_item_count = $leadingcount + 1;
$this->intro_item_count = $counter + 1;
```

And then you can call these variables in the **item_blog** layout (or any layout which belongs to this view class.

(The above is tried and works)

Anyway, I hope this will help you.

Comment: Won't this simply count all of the articles? I only need it to count the articles in say "articles leading" or "articles intro" which are two sections within the blog view. I'm aware this is set in the menu so I could call it from there but if there aren't enough the number will be incorrect. The real reason for my question is to better understand how a variable would be passed, but also because I would want to apply something to each third item. So I need to know which count number is the current one.

Comment: Updated my answer with getting the content params from anywhere, however I do not clearly see your purpose with these numbers and how you would like to use them, so I was not able to give answer on this last part of your question. I think if there are not enough articles for intro for example you can still build a logic for that case too.

Comment: @Eoin - if you mean under passing a variable from a list view layout to an item view layout, and that variable is a foreach loop counter value in the list view layout, then I’d try to solve that with javascript/jQuery for example, since, I would say it is a front-end variable value which is dynamically created in the list view layout file at loading. When you click on an item in a list view layout, the item view layout is getting it’s variables/values from an item view file, and that item layout does not have connection to the list view layout basically, and as I understand that is your issue.

Comment: @Eoin - However you can still “echo out” the counter value to every items into a hidden `<div>` in the list view layout (blog.php) and from that div value you can always see and use that value with jQuery for example in item view layouts (blog_item.php or intro_image.php layout or any other item layout).

Comment: @Eoin - that is how I usually solve this and I see that this is how some other developers usually solve this, since this is a template level logic not a model/view level logic and data.

Comment: @Eoin - and if you need example on this last one I can update my answer with that, as it’s starting to be clear what you are looking for, more precisely.

Comment: My part about the leading items was in case you suggested getting the "number of leading items" from the menu parameter that the user sets.  It looks like you were never going to do that.  Your next solution is an interesting one.  I was trying to set an item in `$displayData` as that is available within the `JLayout` and that does contain many of these parameters.  Is there any value in exploring that as an option rather than adding extra unnecessary markup?

Comment: @Eoin - I updated with a possible solution using the content params registry object. This is also a workable solution for now.

Comment: @Eoin - just getting back to this topic a bit, I understand that you would maybe like to use $displayData but I consider that unnecessary and useless regarding this question, since `$displayData` is an argument array in Layout `render()` method but this topic is about passing a variable (or value) from a layout to another layout (in the same class we hope), contrary to the Layout rendering which method we call usually in/from a view file, not from another Layout file. So I do not see that as a workable direction in this question. Simplest solution is what I gave in the last part of my answer.

Comment: Ok, so now I have another question.  In the `intro image`, I want it to show a `<div>` controlling the width if it exists, and if not, don't show the `<div>`.  I have two columns, 35% and 65%.  If the image isn't available then the 35% doesn't show, but the 65% is not in the `JLayout` it is in `com_content`, is there a way I can then make that 100% if `intro_image` doesn't exist?  I can't do an `if` statement because I don't have access to `intro_image` unless I'm in the `JLayout`.  So I think your answer will allow me to pass information to a `JLayout`, but how can I retrieve info from one?

Comment: I tried adding this to the `JLayout` `<?php
    $content_params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');
    $content_params->set('image_full', htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext));
?>` but it didn't work.  I assume it is because it it's out of context.

Comment: @Eoin - a bit later I'll try to help you with that as I'll get to my laptop...

Comment: I've solved it with a workaround so no rush but I would still like to know the answer.

Comment: @Eoin - do you still work with `blog.php` and `blog_item.php` layout/template files at this task?

Comment: Yes.  and the `JLayout` is `layouts/joomla/content/full_image.php` I would like to determine if the image is set and if not, do some thing in the article, but in a totally different place.  I guess I could just duplicate and rename the JLayout and then do all the work inside there.  That would be a pretty easy workaround.

Comment: @Eoin - it is not easy to tell you without seeing exactly your task but I think you want to use `$this->item` object and in this object you should use `$this->item->images->image_fulltext` which is available before any additional layout is rendered for an item. In a rendered JLayout file `$this->item` becomes `$displayData` object but elsewhere you should be able to use `$this->item`. If we are talking about an article item.

Comment: @Eoin - I also created a fast jQuery/javascript sample about how I usually handle `<div>`'s from front-end if there is an empty `<div>`. I just usually place a short `<script>` at the end of the layout file and it will handle the situation. https://jsfiddle.net/r8wkfnu5/16/
It is about two divs where the widths change depending on whether an image is loaded or not (simulated here by a button click). For you only the 6 lines of codes would be interesting within `afterClick()` function in the sample code.

Comment: @Eoin - I'm sorry I gave you the object property call wrongly above so the correct call is: `json_decode($this->item->images)->image_fulltext` , since `images` property of the object is in `json` format so it has to be decoded first.

Comment: Wow you put in a lot of work, thanks Zollie, I really appreciate it.  This is the most comprehensive answer I've seen to this question.